# Ruby on Rails - keep form values after POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post

There were many solutions described for keeping form values after submit, but I'm looking for more elegant way. Is there some way, not so tedious like getting value for each input control from params hash and not so Rails-version-specific like using vendor plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Please be much more specific and show code.

The most 'elegant' way with Rails is always to use the conventions.
If you `script/rails generate scffold the_name` you will see what gets generated for views and controller.
If you submit a create/edit form and there's an error, rails will take care of preserving the value when it redisplay the form if that is what you want.